# How to copy an image from server directory to another directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, shutil

I am trying to copy an image from a directory on my server and paste is to another file on server. Then I am looking to rename it.

Here is my code (New to python)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import cgi
import os
import shutil

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
username = 'bytesized'
srcfile = 'http://test.com/img/default/basicprof.jpg'
dstroot = 'http://test.com/img/%s.jpg' % username 

assert not os.path.isabs(srcfile)
dstdir =  os.path.join(dstroot, os.path.dirname(srcfile))

os.makedirs(dstdir)
shutil.copy(srcfile, dstdir)
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Is it related to the format string on line 9 by any chance ;)

Comment: No errors, just a blank page with nothing being copied.

Comment: Just did. Still a blank page with no changes in the directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are exactly trying (and asking) but you need to use relative or absolute paths to your image instead of urls.

```
currentpath = '/img/default/basicprof.jpg'
newpathandname = '/img/{}.jpg'.format(username) 

os.rename(currentpath, newpathandname) #does not keep original file
shutil.copyfile(currentpath, newpathandname) #keeps original file
```

Comment: So what i am trying to do if copy an image from one file to another and then rename the one i moved.

Comment: The only issue now is that it removes the original photo. I need that one to always remain in the default directory. I only want a copy that is renamed

Comment: I see, use copyfile(currentpath, newpathandname). copyfile is part of shutil so you need to import it.

Comment: perfect! Thank you for your help.